# Phonegap build não é compatível com php. Como aceder a uma base de dados?

Tags: php, app, phonegap-buillder

Eu criei um website html e acedi à base de dados mysql pelo php. Passei a aplicação para o meu android através do phonegap build da cloud da adobe e percebi que o mesmo não vai buscar os dados por php pois este é do lado do servidor. O que posso fazer para resolver para ter acesso a uma base de dados?
Obrigada. 
Como podem ver a minha app ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Bem conforme a página inicial do [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) diz:

> Crie facilmente aplicativos usando as tecnologias da web que conhecemos e amamos: **HTML**, **CSS** e **JavaScript**

Ou seja ele só aceita essas 3 linguagens e PHP está fora desse contexto. Já respondendo sua pergunta de como você ter acesso a uma base de dados dentro do seu App existe 3 formas nativas, 1 forma externa e outras duas "temporárias", com explico mais a frente.

**1)** Colocando uma base de dados dentro do seu App, atualmente o HTML5 junto ao JavaScript implementaram acesso a banco de dados de forma nativa e offline, ou seja o próprio navegador consegue trabalhar com alguns tipo de bases que explico abaixo.

- [SQLite](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite): O mais famoso e simples ao mesmo tempo, basicamente ele é uma pequena biblioteca, que ao ser iniciada no seu projeto, cria um pequeno arquivo dentro da sua aplicação e esse arquivo será seu banco de dados, e você poderá dar *INSERT*, *UPDATE*, *CREATE* e todos os comandos básicos existente na linguagem [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), com a vantagem de ser leve e ágil, assim como a possibilidade de fazer backup apenas copiando esse arquivo gerado e ser possível usa-lo em outras linguagens com suporte a SQLite como PHP, C#, Java entre outras. Existe vários tutorias e códigos pela web a principio te passo esse - [SQLite offline em dispositivos móveis com HTML5](http://blog.vilourenco.com.br/como-criar-sqlite-offline-em-dispositivos-moveis-com-html5/) - mas recomendo ler o máximo que possível para aprender sobre ele.
- [WebSQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/): Já o WebSQL tem o conceito BEM parecido com o SQLite *(alguns dizem que é apenas o SQLite embutido dentro do navegador)* a diferença é que foi criada pelo W3C é que essa biblioteca é focada apenas no uso dentro do navegador, ela tem suas particularidades também em questão de funcionamento mas não muitas, outro detalhe é que nem todos navegadores ainda esta com essa biblioteca em plena funcionalidade, eu posso te recomendar esse tutorial para a leitura - [Trabalhando com o Web SQL Database do HTML5](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/trabalhando-com-o-web-sql-database-do-html5) - mas diferente do SQLite acredito que irá encontrar uma documentação e exemplos em menor quantidade enquanto essa tecnologia não se torna mais madura.
- [IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/IndexedDB/Usando_IndexedDB): Bem ele também é um banco de dados que funciona internamente apenas dentro do navegador, porém sua maior diferença entre o WebSQL e o SQLite é que ele não funciona com SQL como os anteriores e sim com chaves e valores estilo o [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-pt.html) então ele é mais parecido com um banco de dados ["Não Relacional (NoSQL)"](http://www.fxplabs.com.br/blog/nosql-conceito-de-banco-de-dados-nao-relacional/) do que um banco de dados ["Relacional (SQL)"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_relacional#Por_que_usar_um_Banco_de_Dados_Relacional.3F).

**2)** Bem a segunda forma de se fazer isso é usar meios externos, como uma [API](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es), hospedando em uma máquina externa e fazendo sua aplicação acessa-lá remotamente, a desvantagem é o usuário ser obrigado a estar sempre com internet, tempo de acesso a API, segurança e o aumento da complexidade do sistema, porém em alguns casos é necessário o uso de uma API, como por exemplo um sistema de chat onde a mensagem sai de um lugar e vai para outro precisa de um ponto de controle, ou um sistema de comentário estilo do Facebook.

No seu caso, como já disse ter um pedaço de código pronto em PHP, você teria que hospedar esses seus arquivos em um servidor, e fazer algumas adaptações para que as chamadas retornassem JSON ou XML por exemplo e essas por sua vez fossem apresentadas no seu App. Para isso você poderia até usar o [JQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/) para criar as chamadas e exibições dos conteúdos, vou dar um pequeno exemplo abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "http://seudominio.com/catalogo.php",
 success: function(result) {
  alert(result); // Mostra os dados gerado pelo PHP + DB
 } 
});
```

**3)** Um terceiro método de se gravar informações em um App seria por meio dos [Cookies](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_HTTP) ou [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), já que estamos falando de um App hibrido (através do PhoneGap) nada mais justo que usar tecnologias da Web, e digo que se você precisa gravar pequenas informações e não precisa de segurança diria que esse é o cara indicado, eu mesmo já usei cookies em um joguinho que fiz com o PhoneGap, no meu caso eu gravava a última pontuação alcançada pelo usuário e me servia bem.

- Cookies: Bem essa tecnologia você já deve ter ouvido a exaustão por ai, ela consiste em um pequeno arquivo que recebe um nome e um valor, você podre gravar, ler e deletar esse pequeno arquivo a hora que quiser, e o JavaScript consegue fazer todas essas operações, aqui tem um tutorial de como fazer isso - [JavaScript Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).
- localStorage: Essa tecnologia é nova e foi implementa no HTML5, mas é bem parecida com os cookies a vantagem dela é o tamanho de armazenamento (5MB), melhor tempo de leitura e escrita sem afetar a performance e melhoramento da segurança dos dados, aqui você irá encontrar um tutorial também - [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

*PS.: Eu coloquei vários links, sei que não é recomendado, mas a reposta para essa pergunta é bem ampla, e envolve muitos códigos e exemplo, sem contar que precisa ver qual a tecnologia que ela pretende usar, qual a sua real necessidade, e qual seu grau de conhecimento sobre essas tecnologias, então é apenas uma direção e não um tutorial de como fazer.*

Comment: API, por mim, é a melhor opção. Um hibrido talvez fosse ideal, salvando alguns dados no lado do cliente e outros coletando (e atualizando) via API.

Comment: Triste ver uma resposta tão completa e tão útil não sendo marcada como solução e nem +1 pelo autor da pergunta...